# Laravel 5.4 encrypter exception

Tags: ajax, laravel, exception, encryption

I know that this is common question, but my application works fine basically. This error pops up randomly after some ajax calls `The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.`. Is it framework bug or something else?

Comment: run `php artisan key:generate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have that issue before and its gone running:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Is there a reason why cache has been 'broken'? Will it occur later in production?

Comment: I really don´t know why happend, but never happen to me in production. you should mark the answer as correct to help other people in future.